# Getting an error related to \prevdepth when using \caption on a figure with subfloats

Tags: floats, errors, captions, subfloats

I am writing a manuscript and I am using the `subfloat` package to include in a figure several figures, if I don't include a caption it compiles nicely, but when including the caption I get the error

`! Improper \prevdepth`.

I have tried using the caption package too but doesn't seem to work.
What I have looks like:

```
\documentclass[aps,preprint,pra]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat{
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\hline \hline
First Column & Second column \\[1ex]
\hline

 \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{figure1} &\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{figure2} \\[0.5ex]

\hline \hline
\end{tabular}
}\caption{Caption for figures 1 and 2}\label{fig1and2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If someone can comment on this I will really appreciate it.
Thanks,

Comment: Your code compiles without problems on my TeXLive 2014 installation

Comment: Remember to do `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}` with `revtex4-1`

Comment: @egreg Thank you so much!! that does the trick, now it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always call

```
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
```

with the `revtex4-1` document class, which is not compatible with `caption`. The option is indeed meant not to load the `caption` package along with `subfig` (it will emulate the needed features).

Note that it's better avoiding blank lines inside `\subfloat` (not required, though). More importantly, you're missing some `%` and getting unwanted spaces:

```
\subfloat{% <----------- important
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
  ...
  \end{tabular}% <------ important
}
\caption{...}\label{...}
```